# Stall POST form to update documents in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, post, express

So the essential idea is to stall a POST form so that I can gather more data.

Currently : I am working on an application to speed up testing on certain views. So I render one view, via HTML canvas element, the user votes on the view through a form and hits submit, and the form gets sent to MongoDB as a document. Then the page refreshes, which I know is best practice.

However, with this application, I want to loop through several views so a user can test multiple views. Ideally, every time a user would submit a form, a Mongo document will update with the user's results, and a new view will be rendered through a function call until the final view is called, but this is hindered because I am not too sure how to deal with the response.

My form.jade file:

```
block content
    .container
        .well
            form.form-horizontal(name="resultSubmit" method="post" action="/create")
                fieldset
                    legend PDF Metrology
                    .form-group
                        label.col-md-2.control-label(for="Name") Name
                        .col-md-10
                            input#Name(name="Name" value=name type="text" placeholder="John Smith" required).form-control.input-lg
                    .form-group
                        label.col-md-2.control-label(for="selectbasic") Select One
                        .col-md-10
                            select#selectbasic(name="better_pdf").form-control
                                option(value=-2) U is much better than S
                                option(value=-1) U is better than S
                                option(value=0) U is the same as S
                                option(value=1) S is better than U
                                option(value=2) S is much better than U
                    .form-group
                        label.col-md-2.control-label(for="printS") Is S good enough to print?
                        .col-md-10
                            label.radio-inline(for="radios-1")
                                input#radios-1(type="radio" name="printS" value=1 checked="checked")
                                | Yes
                            label.radio-inline(for="radios-0")
                                input#radios-0(type="radio" name="printS" value=0)
                                | No
                    .form-group
                        .col-md-10.col-md-offset-2
                        .pull-right
                            button(type="submit").btn.btn-primary Submit
```

My form handling post which is used through an app.js file

```
/* POST form */
router.post('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null,err);

        console.log(req.body);

        var collection = db.collection('pdf_models');
        var doc = req.body;

        collection.insertOne(doc, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(err,null);
            console.log("Inserted a document: " + JSON.stringify(doc));
            db.close();
        });
    });

    res.send('It worked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
router.post('/create', function(req,res)
```